# What is the difference between "for(int i=0,length=list.size;i<length;i++) " and "for(int i=0;i<list.size;i++) "?

Tags: java

I saw two ways of writing for loops.

```
for( int i = 0, length = list.size(); i < length; i++ )
```

and

```
for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
```

Is their performance the same? Will the jvm optimize the difference？

Comment: stop worrying about micro optimisation and write easier to understand code.

Comment: Nice "？" question, but as @MitchWheat said, 'write easier to understand code.' Don't worry about optimizing something like this as its speed isn't going to be but a couple millisecond faster, and a millisecond is only a thousandth of a second.

Comment: millisecond? more like microsecond

Comment: @TyQ. Actually, the Java compiler might even optimize both versions to the same thing.  But yeah, what Mitch Wheat said.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with Java and its compilers, but I know a bit of it, and I'm becoming more and more familiar with C++ and *its* compilers. And from what I understand, it is true that compilers have a tendency to optimize things exactly the same even if one was intended to be faster than the other.

Comment: What everyone else has said, but also - this is why all the cool kids like enhanced for-each loops. It hides `i` which makes the code easier to reason about.

Comment: ...and if you micro-optimize for one compiler, even the next patch update might pessimize your code..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Java compiler performs extremely little optimization, and it certainly won't do something that changes semantics (in this case, the OP failed to properly write `list.size()`).

Comment: @chrylis Then perhaps my comment is unfounded (though still not as bad the answer below :P).

Comment: @MitchWheat: Microseconds? You mean nanoseconds.

Comment: Most computers will have no problem executing single instructions faster than a nanosecond. However, how many of those you gain depends on the size of the list in this instance. Given a large enough list, it is possible to break into the millisecond range in difference between caching `.size()` versus calling it at each iteration. Does that single or several millisecond difference matter? I guess it depends on what you are doing. Perhaps if it is tracking the path of something very sensitive (gaming comes to mind) it matters.

Comment: Otherwise, a very smart person once told me, never worry about anything less than 40 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

These two for loops are not equivalent when the size changes while in the loop block. The first one may fail with an index out of range or may miss added elements.

Performance: Compilers optimize the most common cases. So I wouldn't do anything special to try to optimize something as common as looping a collection.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is that the first way only calls `list.size()` once instead of on each iteration. It's unlikely to be useful with a simple list, but it can be helpful when it's expensive to compute `length`; for example, when [iterating over a `NodeList`](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#iil-nodelist-getlength-called-in-a-loop-iil-elements-get-length-in-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make code easier to read to help answer your questions.

The following tests are based on javase 8:

i will list the java byte codes for the two different codes:

```
public void gg1(List<String> list){
    for(int i = 0, length = list.size(); i < length; i++){

    }
}
```

the byte code is:

```
public gg1(Ljava/util/List;)V
   L0
   LINENUMBER 10 L0
   ICONST_0
   ISTORE 2
  L1
   ALOAD 1
   INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/List.size ()I
   ISTORE 3
  L2
   GOTO L3
  L4
  FRAME APPEND [I I]
   IINC 2 1
  L3
  FRAME SAME
   ILOAD 2
   ILOAD 3
   IF_ICMPLT L4
  L5
   LINENUMBER 13 L5
   RETURN
  L6
   LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/trans/test/Test14; L0 L6 0
   LOCALVARIABLE list Ljava/util/List; L0 L6 1
   // signature Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;
   // declaration: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
   LOCALVARIABLE i I L1 L5 2
   LOCALVARIABLE length I L2 L5 3
   MAXSTACK = 2
   MAXLOCALS = 4
```

Now in the other code:

```
 public void gg2(List<String> list){
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){

    }
}
```

the byte code is:

```
public gg2(Ljava/util/List;)V
  L0
   LINENUMBER 16 L0
   ICONST_0
   ISTORE 2
  L1
   GOTO L2
  L3
  FRAME APPEND [I]
   IINC 2 1
  L2
  FRAME SAME
   ILOAD 2
   ALOAD 1
   INVOKEINTERFACE java/util/List.size ()I
   IF_ICMPLT L3
  L4
   LINENUMBER 19 L4
   RETURN
  L5
   LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/trans/test/Test14; L0 L5 0
   LOCALVARIABLE list Ljava/util/List; L0 L5 1
   // signature Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;
   // declaration: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
   LOCALVARIABLE i I L1 L4 2
   MAXSTACK = 2
   MAXLOCALS = 3
```

It can be seen that the list.size() method will be invoked in every iteration of gg2, and invoked once in the method gg1. Therefore, gg1 is more efficient!

I hope this helps answer your question!

Comment: i also tried the performance between the two different write type.